# Year-Month data appears in wrong format

Tags: r, time-series, data-manipulation

I converted my data into year-month format using as.yearmon(), and the result was that:

[Result 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6aipB.jpg)

The problem is: When I plot a chart, the time period appears just in years like: 2017.0 instead of 2017/Jan or something else.

[Problem outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO2lQ.jpg)

Comment: Please post your code and output, don't just use image links.

Comment: See `?scale_x_yearmon`

Answer (score 1):

Thank you G. Grothendieck. I just have included scale_x_yearmon(), and the problem was solved.